# How to add element to this array?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to add new items into this array?

```
            RowMsg RowMsg_data[] = new RowMsg[] {

                    new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 1"),
                    new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 2"),
                    new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 3"),
                    new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 4")

            };

            // here i want add next one element, for example: RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 5")
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't add elements to arrays - once you've created the array, its size can't change.

You'd be better off with a list:

```
List<RowMsg> messages = new ArrayList<RowMsg>();
messages.add(new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 1"));
// etc
```

As an aside, it's more conventional to keep the type information all in one place, and Java variables are conventionally camel-cased - so even if you *did* stick with your array, it would be better to declare it as:

```
RowMsg[] rowMsgData = new RowMsg[] {
    ...
};
```

(I'd also suggest avoiding abbreviations, but there we go.)

Answer (score 1):

If you ***really*** need `RowMsg_data` to be an *array* do

```
RowMsg_data = new ArrayList<RowMsg>(Arrays.asList(RowMsg_data))
               .add(new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 5"))
               .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `ArrayList`, then you won't have to re-allocate another bigger array and copy from your first array, that is all handled by `ArrayList`.

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of an array after initalization. Use a `List` e.g. `ArrayList<RowMsg>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    RowMsg_data = Arrays.copyOf(RowMsg_data, RowMsg_data.length);
    RowMsg_data[RowMsg_data - 1] = new RowMsg(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message 5");
```